How to run a pre build script in gnat project file?
I have a mixed C++ and Ada project.
A GPRbuild project is used to build it and there is no makefile.
There is a script which creates an H file with constants such as build host, username and git commit.
How do I run the script before compiling the file that import its result?
I did not find a gprbuild option for pre/post build steps, probably because it breaks portability.
What is the common practice in this case?

Why not run gprbuild from the script?

@JeffreyR.Carter No, I want to run the script before compilation step in gprbuild.

You can't do this with gprbuild (for now?). Try to use Alire. It's fantastic for dependency management and can run simple post-fetch, pre-build, post-build actions.
